# Where can I find errata for Psionics Unleashed/Ultimate Psionics?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, errata, dreamscarred-press

I recall, at one point, there being a collection of patches to Dreamscarred Press's psionics content, found on their forum, but it seems that in the time since I checked it, they've replaced their old forum with a new one.

Where can I find critical patches for my softcover copy of the original *Psionics Unleashed*, or my 2013 digital version of *Ultimate Psionics*, to give to my players and to rely on when rules conflicts come up?

The text found on external sites like d20pfsrd or the Library of Metzofitz will not do for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

By use of the fantastic [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/), I was able to find an archived copy of the forum thread you mentioned - although sadly only the first page of the thread, so only the first 20 posts of it. The thread does go onto a second page but it's not obvious how many more posts there were. For some reason, errata seems to be split between edits to the original post at the top of the thread and individual mentions in later posts - you'd have to read them all to get the complete picture.

This [2015-03-10 archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310092743/http://dreamscarredpress.com:80/dragonfly/ForumsPro/viewtopic/t=979.html)  is the last copy that the Wayback Machine has prior to the forum death, but it's got broken CSS/images. This [2015-01-21 archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150121024757/http://dreamscarredpress.com:80/dragonfly/ForumsPro/viewtopic/t=979.html) is a slightly earlier copy, but the content is the same, and it still has working styling so it's a bit easier on the eyes.

Despite suggesting that he would, there doesn't seem to be any indication that Jeremy ever restored this topic from his SQL dump of the old forum when they set up the new one, or that anyone has published a compilation of this errata anywhere else. The Wayback archive was the best I could find.